# Android network reachability (offline mode)?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, connectivity

So I am calling few different web services in my app but I want to check if the device is able to connect to internet before service is called.

First I created a static Flag.

`public static bool IsOfflineMode = false;`

And before each service is called, I add the following:

```
if(IsOfflineMode) {
    return;
}
```

This is how I am checking if the device is online or not.

```
public bool isConnected()
{
    ConnectivityManager connectManager = (ConnectivityManager)GetSystemService (Context.ConnectivityService);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = connectManager.ActiveNetworkInfo;

    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.IsConnectedOrConnecting) {
        NetworkInfo wifi = connectManager.GetNetworkInfo (ConnectivityType.Wifi);
        NetworkInfo mobile = connectManager.GetNetworkInfo (ConnectivityType.Mobile);

        if ((mobile != null && mobile.IsConnectedOrConnecting) || (wifi != null && wifi.IsConnectedOrConnecting)) {
            return true;
        } else { 
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And then assign the value of `isConnected()` to `IsOfflineMode`.

`IsOfflineMode = !isConnected ();`

But I don't want to call `isConnected()` every time.

How can I put a trigger so that when the device goes offline/online, it changes the value of `IsOfflineMode` ?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Create a [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) responding to the action `<action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>`

Hope it helps!

Comment: That is right. Read further in the docs here : http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html